# Power BI connection problem with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, database-connection

I'm using Power BI version 2.84 to connect to Postgresql server. In PBI desktop everything works fine, I can connect to the server, import and refresh data smoothly.
However when I publish it to PBI server, I can't refresh it anymore due to 'encrypted connection'. I have checked all of my connection settings and make sure they are not encrypted at all but the problem is still there.
Please let me know if you have any solution for this.
Cheers

Comment: You'd have to share your configuration and a literal quote of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using direct query?

If you want to use direct query you will need to set up On-Premises data gateway.
[on premise gateways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-onprem)

And then you should add gateway cluster in PowerBI web version [gateway cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-high-availability-clusters):

[Data gateway](https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/gateways/)

I think everything is quite straightforward here.

But do you need direct query? If you are ok with refreshing your data a few times a day, you could set up a ODBC connection (when importing data, choose ODBC option not postgresql).

You would need to set up ODBC drivers, (Control panel -> Administrative tools -> Data sources) And create a new one (you should download [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/) ODBC driver if you have none)

Then you also need to create On-Premises data gateway and set up refresh intervals.

Comment: I don't use direct query. But yeah using gateway really helps. Bunch of thanks!!!